# How to measure voltage induced in coil due to an oscillating bar magnet using null method?

Tags: electric-current, capacitance, electromagnetic-induction

Here we're trying to measure the maximum emf induced in the coil using null method.

I can understand what the book means by 'a kick'. I can't understand how this circuit works. For example, how is the voltmeter connected in series to the capacitor and the coil?

> The peak value of the emf generated may also be measured
> by using null method in which one compares the varying emf
> with a d-c voltage. The arrangement is shown in figure 7.3. The
> voltmeter will record a ’kick’ if the voltage across AB(potential
> divider) is smaller than the peak voltage developed across the
> coil so that all that is required is to increase the d-c voltage until
> the meter ceases to show any deflection. The part played by the
> capacitor is purely nominal.
> [image: Circuit]